# RobotFramework: WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Attr value="107592"]

Tags: robotframework

My code is:

```
${value}  xpath: (//div[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UltraWebTab1_div0']//table)[3]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[3]/@value

Page Should Contain Element  ${value}  loglevel=TRACE
```

but the respons is:
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Attr value="107592"]

the thing I need is:
the input field has no value, then it gets a random value.

how do i verify it got any value?

Comment: share html code snippet as well

Answer (score 0):

made this:
Should Be Equal  ${value}  ${value}

where ${value} =

```
${value}  xpath: (//div[@id='specimen_div0']//table)[3]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[3]/@value
```

at that point the @value must be there, so it checks against itself.

does it make sense or? does anyone has a better solution??